# (Javascript) why borderBottomRightRadius sets as borderRadius?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

i have 5 inputs type range, when you use em, a image change its border radius property:

```
<div class="element" id="element">
    
</div>
<div class="ranges">

    <label for="" class="label">0</label>
    <input type="range" class="range" id="range-1" value="0" min="0" max="50">
    
    <label for="" class="label">0</label>
    <input type="range" class="range" id="range-2" value="0" min="0" max="50">

    <label for="" class="label">0</label>
    <input type="range" class="range" id="range-3" value="0" min="0" max="50">
    
    <label for="" class="label">0</label>
    <input type="range" class="range" id="range-4" value="0" min="0" max="50">
    
    <label for="" class="label">0</label>
    <input type="range" class="range" id="range-5" value="0" min="0" max="50">

</div>
```

the div with the class "element" contains the image to modify:

The problem happens when i use the 4 input: it should change the border-bottom-right-radius property, but changes border-radius:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set a `break;` at line 45 :)

Comment: Thank you!   ;)  i thought it was a javascript bug